# Rails 4 select_tag with blank and selected

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a select html element in Rails 4 but am not managing to get everything I want to work at the same time.

I have a controller which has a route of `/rule_search` with:

```
def index
  # RuleType is an AR model and only has the columns `id` and `name`
  @rule_types = RuleType.all

  # I would like to be able to access a param such as the below example when the form is submitted
  @rule_type_id = params[:rule_type_id]
end
```

I have a view called index.html.erb on which I have a form.

```
<h2>Rule Search</h2>
<%= form_tag("/rule_search", method: "post") do %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Rule Type</td>
    <td><%= # Select Element Goes Here %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag(:name, "Search for:") %></td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag(:name, @name) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want there to be a blank value on the select element which will always be selectable, even if the user previously selected a real value.  A 'None' option rather than a prompt.

I want the selected value from the previous form submission to persist on the select element.

I want to use `form_tag` rather than `form_for` as I am not trying to create an AR object with this form.  I am just trying to make a simple select element which persists its own selection and submits its value to the controller with the rest of the form.

Comment: The closest I can get is `<%= select_tag(:rule_type_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@rule_types, :id, :name)) %>` (untested and assuming your @rule_types each have an `:id` and a `:name`).  I think `:include_blank` happens by default although I am not certain.  I don't believe it is an allowed option for the `select_tag`.

Comment: Strange that there is not a select option, if that is the case I will write my own helper.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need. Rails may also have a simple syntax for this but this should do what you are looking for.

```
<tr>
<td>Rule Type</td>
<td>
    <select>
       <% @rule_types.each do |rule| %>
           <option><%= rule %></option>
       <% end %>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not include either the "None" or the "Selected" part of the problem.